# Change the @Component being injected in tests

Tags: java, spring, testing, dependency-injection

I have two classes

```
@Component
public class A {

  @Autowired
  B b;
}

@Component
public class B {
}
```

They're found via scan by Spring.

Now I'd like to test `A`, but I'd need to provide a different impl. of `B`, say `BMock`.

How can I make Spring to find the different `B` rather than the standard (only one in production) one?

I have my tests annotated with:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:/test-context.xml")
```

in which file some instances (DAO, ..) are defined, and then in the test class I write

```
@Autowired
A testInstance;
```

Comment: This is an excellent example of why constructor injection is usually better than field injection. If you rewrite your class to take `B` in its constructor, you don't need anything complicated to run your tests.

Comment: @chrylis I actually like your solution best I think, so simple.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need Spring for that. That's the whole point of dependency injection: you're able to inject whatever you want, explicitely, in your unit tests. Unit tests should not use Spring.

```
// constructor injection
B mockB = mock(B.class);
A aUnderTest = new A(mockB);
```

or

```
// setter injection
B mockB = mock(B.class);
A aUnderTest = new A();
aUnderTest.setB(mockB);
```

or

```
// Field injection, requiring reflection, done by Mockito
@Mock
private B mockB;

@InjectMocks
private A aUnderTest;

@Before
public void initMocks() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

Comment: not using mockito, I dont want to mock but provide a test implementation

Comment: The principle is the same. You create your fake implementation, and construct the object under test with this fake implementation. If you don't want to use reflection, then use constructor or setter injection instead of field injection.

Answer (score 0):

You can create separate xml file for testing purpose and inject another object of B (BMock) and in production you can inject B. SO, there are two separate configuration file one for production and other for testing.

Comment: Yeah I actually ended up removing `@Component` and adding an element in the XML; now I simply have a different entry (bean) for production XML and different for test XML. **Any anaologous solution when using annotations?**

Comment: You do not need to remove annotations. You can use both. Annotations are just overwrite when xml file is present

Comment: XML has precedence? What if they are 2 different classes implementing a same interface

Comment: Not precedence. XML injections is performed after annotations injection. So it will overwrite if there is any annotated dependency. For second question you can use @Qualifier

Comment: @Qualifier inject bean by name

Answer (score 0):

As per the `Spring documentation`

```
Annotation injection is performed before XML injection, thus the latter 
configuration will override the former for properties wired through both approaches.
```

So you can overwrite `Spring context` file in your test environment giving test implementation. But if you have several implementations you cannot work with `@Autowire` alone. You need to use `@Qualifier` as well. So best way to do is `mock` the test implementation and inject it using setter as [JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26522043/change-the-component-being-injected-in-tests/26522187#26522187) answered